# Need help to identify a component - switch

Tags: switches, identification, repair

I recently bought a (Power Rangers SPD) Dekaranger Morpher for my kid (Japanese version of a Power Rangers toy) and 2 of the switches on the board are damaged.

I know I can buy something similar and struggle to find the specific switch, however I have no idea what to look for, so I'm coming to you to search for answers.

If it helps in some way I live in the northern part of Mexico and I haven't found anything similar in my local electronics stores. Googling about these switches, the only thing I found was to get a damaged one for parts and take them from there.

BTW I was redirected here by the Ask Electronics subreddit.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I uploaded a better pic

Comment: Have a look at [here](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/filter/tactile-switches/197?s=N4IgjCBcoGwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIALAAxwUBMVIhFYYcdEzr7jAuoQAcALlBABlIQCcAlgDsA5iAC%2BSwgFZEIAVDCDtkOmpVA). I hope you can find at least a similar one.

Comment: This looks like what's sold as "detector switch" on [Mouser](https://www.mouser.de/c/electromechanical/switches/detector-switches/?termination%20style=SMD%2FSMT) or "microswitch" on [LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com/products/Microswitches_426.html). If you want a more specific answer, you'll need to add measurements to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Please, check these parts: [HDP001L](https://www.digikey.pl/pl/products/detail/c-k/HDP001L/5030191) or [HDP001R](https://www.digikey.pl/pl/products/detail/c-k/HDP001R/5030192).

[image]